# Spark RDD and Dataframe transformation optimisation

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to Spark and have the following high level question about RDDs and Dataframes which if im not mistaken are built on top of RDDs:

I understand that there are two types of operations that can be done on RDD's, transformations and actions. I also understand that transformations are only executed when an action is performed on an RDD that is a product of that transformation. Given that RDD's are in memory, I was wondering if there was some possibility of optimising the amount of memory consumed by these RDDs, take the following example:

```
KafkaDF = KafkaDFRaw.select(
        KafkaDFRaw.key,
        KafkaDFRaw.value,
        KafkaDFRaw.topic,
        unix_timestamp('timestamp',
                       'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').alias('kafka_arrival_time')
    ).withColumn("spark_arrival_time", udf(time.time, DoubleType())())
```

I have a KafkaDFRaw dataframe and I produce a new RDD called KafkaDF. I then wish to add columns to this new RDD. Should I add them to the existing RDD? Like so:

```
decoded_value_udf = udf(lambda value: value.decode("utf-8"))
    KafkaDF = KafkaDF\
        .withColumn(
            "cleanKey", decoded_value_udf(KafkaDF.key))\
        .withColumn(
            "cleanValue", decoded_value_udf(KafkaDF.value))
```

Or should I create a new dataframe from the last one? Like so:

```
decoded_value_udf = udf(lambda value: value.decode("utf-8"))
    KafkaDF_NEW = KafkaDF\
        .withColumn(
            "cleanKey", decoded_value_udf(KafkaDF.key))\
        .withColumn(
            "cleanValue", decoded_value_udf(KafkaDF.value))
```

Does this make a difference in terms of memory optimisation?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your both options are identical. RDDs and dataframes are immutable, and the 1st option simply reassigns new rdd to the same variable. Another note -- you can't create new rdd within a task, so if your intent for the `udf` to be distributed then its not going to work.

Comment: @mazaneicha. Thanks for your reply and feedback. I see what you are saying, but then how would you make it distributed?

Comment: New rdds /dataframes can only be created on the driver that defined SparkContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the action is called, the optimized dag gets executed and the memory is used as per the plan.
You can compare the execution plans to understand:

```
df.explain(true)
df_new.explain(true)
```

Creating extra variable in between to hold the transformations does not impact the memory utilization. Memory requirements will depend on data size, partition size, shuffles etc.